# RODBC error - ODBC connection failed - can't connect to MySQL with my mac (mavericks)

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to a mysql database through R using RODBC on my mac (mavericks) but after a stupid number of hours of effort, I still can't get it working.  When I try to connect to a database, RODBC throws this error (error message is so terse, I don't know what it means):

> ch <- odbcConnect("mydatabasename") "Warning messages: 1: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=mydatabase") :   [RODBC] ERROR: state H, code 0, message [unixODBC][ 2: In odbcDriverConnect("DSN=mydatabasename") : ODBC connection failed"

I got to where I am at by following the instructions at the following blog (install unixODBC):
http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/09/18/setup-odbc-for-r-on-os-x/

It shows me that I am connected, if I enter:

> isql -v mydatabasename

I installed R from source and the install worked with no noticeable errors, but now when I try to connect to a database from Rstudio, with:

> ch <- odbcConnect("mydatabasename")

I get the ODBC connection failed error.  Can anyone help me understand what this error means? Or how I could potentially fix it? Or who I can talk with to get some help?

You would keep me from shooting myself.  haha!  But seriously... you would.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem as you've reported.
My ODBC connection was using the MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver (/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so)
Although I could connect with iSQL, actual SQL commands were returning garbage.

I tried changing my odbc.ini to use the the ANSI driver instead (/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5a.so).
It worked and now RODBC can connect to my MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out switching from `/libmyodbc5w.so` to `/libmyodbc5a.so` drivers fixes the issue.